# NVIDIA streaming and network services will randomly start

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card

NVIDIA's Steaming and Network service processes will begin to randomly turn themselves on. I have these services disabled through Startup, since I only have a GeForce 560 that doesn't support NVIDIA's streaming service, and the networking features are useless to me at this point. About once a month though, I will notice that these processes are running again, even after restarts. MSCONFIG claims that they're still disabled on startup, yet they continue to run.

Only after I enabled and disabled the services again will the "Date Disabled" field update to the current day, and the services will stop running on startup.

I realize this is a fairly ambiguous question, but why does this happen? What would cause them to randomly start during use, and continue to run on startup until I enable/disable them again?

I can provide any additional details needed.

Comment: @Hennes, why edit this now? It's over 6 months old.

Comment: As part of the deprecated tags cleanup. See [this post on meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your scheduled Tasks. You'll be surprised at what yiu may find. For example, Google Chrome and Adobe updates can be found in the Scheduled Tasks to start the serivice. If the scheduled Task is there, remove it and you should be good.

Comment: I don't see anything NVIDIA related, only from Microsoft and Apple.